# I want to add a namespace prefix to the tags of the default name space of an XML document from the shell

Tags: xml, xmllint, xmlstarlet

I have a SVG file, which is an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
  <!-- a lot of stuff> </defs>
  <!-- more stuff-->
</svg>
```

I want to add the svg: prefix to all the tags corresponding to the default namespace in order to get next output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg:svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <svg:defs
     id="defs2">
  <!-- a lot of stuff> </svg:defs>
  <!-- more stuff-->
</svg:svg>
```

I am sure this is possible in one or few command lines from the shell using **xmllint** and/or **xmlstarlet** but I can't manage it.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since you asked. Nevertheless ...

`xmlstarlet edit`'s `-r` / `--rename` action requires a literal value
for the new name so XPath functions are out. However, `xmlstarlet select`
can be used as a code generator to produce the edit command:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -t \
  --var sq -o "'" -b \
  -o 'xmlstarlet edit --pf \' -n \
  -m 'set:distinct(//_:*)' \
    -o '  -r ' -v 'concat($sq,"//_:",local-name(),$sq)' \
    -o '  -v ' -v 'concat($sq,"svg:",local-name(),$sq)' -o ' \' -n \
  -b \
  -f -n \
file.xml
```

where

- the `//_:*` expression matches all element nodes in the default namespace
  (the `_` shortcut is in the `xmlstarlet` [user's guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html))
- the EXSLT function [`set:distinct`](https://exslt.github.io/set/functions/distinct/index.html)
  eliminates duplicates
- `-o` outputs a string literal, `-n` a newline, `-f` the input
  pathname / URL (but `-` for stdin)
- `-b` ends the current container (`-m`, `--var` without `=`, a.o.)
- adding a `-C` option before `-t` lists the generated XSLT code

Output:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit --pf \
  -r '//_:svg'  -v 'svg:svg' \
  -r '//_:defs'  -v 'svg:defs' \
file.xml
```

where

- `-P` / `--pf` preserves original formatting
- adding an `-L` / `--inplace` option after `edit` supports in-place
  editing (not in the user's guide but in
  [xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt))

To execute the output as a shell script:

```sh
xmlstarlet-select-command | sh -s > result.xml
```

In case you want to avoid EXSLT, instead `-m '//_:*' --sort 'A:T:-' .`
and pipe the output through `uniq`, or simply `-m '//_:*'` with
possible duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet`in a particularly brutal fashion (I await the proper xpath)

```
for x in $(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*" -n -v "name()" file1.xml | sort | uniq); do 
    xmlstarlet ed -r "//svg:$x" -v "svg:$x" file1.xml > tmp.xml;
    mv tmp.xml file1.xml;
done
```

Since you have declared the namespace `svg` already, you need to invoke it in the `xpath` to change the literal value of the node names.

Comment: what is the command **xml** you use on the second line?

Comment: the `xml` command is just an alias for `xmlstarlet`. Same tool.

Comment: OK. In my configuration, the alias **xml** is not available by default. So I will write **xmlstarlet** instead.